# Notification for ’A pull request is created or updated‘ is not working when application-tier is Simplified-Chinese

Tags: azure-devops

#### - Version:

1. azure devops Dev17.M153.5
2. sql server 15.0.2000

#### - Reproducible Steps:

1. Install the azure devops 2019 1.1
2. **Configure the application-tier as Simplified-Chinese**
3. Finish the installation
4. Create the team notification for ’A pull request is created or updated‘
5. Check the mailbox

#### Information：

1. PR notification email was not received
2. Follow the [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/use-subscription-logging?view=azure-devops-2020) and we got the following message:

```
"messages":[{"level":1,"time":"11:23:40.2682787","message":
"设置电子邮件格式时出错。将改为发送一条错误消息。
MustacheExpressionInvalidException:对于表达式“stringFormat“在 {0} 中打开”event.secondaryToolName”找不到帮助程序“stringFormat“在”
@MustacheTemplatedExpression..ctor:0
@MustacheExpression.Parse:0
@ContributedTemplateServiceBase`1.ParseFieldToken:0
@ContributedTemplateServiceBase`1.ParseFieldToken:0
@ContributedTemplateServiceBase`1.ParseFieldToken:0
@ContributedTemplateServiceBase`1.ParseFieldToken:0
"
```

#### - We have tried :

1. Double-check the [Why am I not getting an email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops) ---- No issue is against the rules in the guidance
2. Try another notification type, such as "Work item is created" or "A build completes" ---- We can receive the related email
3. Remove the application-tier which has been initialized as Simplified-Chinese, and **re-initialize** the new application-tier **as  English**-----**The expected PR notification email was RECEIVED** ！！！

Answer (score 0):

In order to narrow down the issue, you could try the following items:

1. Check whether you have the latest patch installed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019u1?view=azure-devops
2. If you configure the application-tier as Simplified-Chinese again, would you be able to see the issue agine?
3. Check in other team projects to see whether you can reproduce this issue.
4. Create a new team project collection, and create a new team project in it, to see whether you can reproduce this issue.
5. Check the event log in Event Viewer, to see whether there is useful information.

Comment: 1. We tried 2019 1.1 patch 6 and 7, but it seems helpless to the issue. The others patches are in the schedule. 2. Yes, same exception 3. Yes, same exception 4. Yes, same exception 5. Could you give some link for guidance？

Comment: I'll set up environment to test this scenario, and let you know the result later.